# Getting latest date in a partition by year / month / day using SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to incrementally transform new partitions in a source table into a new table using Spark SQL.  The data in both the source and target are partitioned as follows: `/data/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/`. I was initially just going to select the MAX of `year`, `month` and `day` to get the newest partition, but that is clearly wrong. Is there is a good way to do this?

If I construct a date and take the max like `MAX( CONCAT(year,'-','month','-',day)::date )` this would be quite ineffecient, right? Because it will need to scan all data to pull the newest partition.

Comment: _select the MAX of year, month and day to get the newest partition, but that is clearly wrong_ - why? Should be fine, as long as fields are in correct order (year, month, day).

Comment: Let's say it is Jan 10, 2020 and select the max day. As the `MAX(day)` will be 31, and `MAX(month)` is 12, I will be looking for records greater than `2020-12-31`. To get this right, you need to treate the 3 partitions as a single logical unit. At least, I think you do.

Answer (score 0):

Try below to get the latest partition without reading data at all, only metadata:

```
spark.sql("show partitions <table>").agg(max('partition)).show
```

Comment: that would not provide the correct result for partitions as the values will get sorted based on a string value ie.  `year=2019/month=11/day=5` would be less than `year=2019/month=9/day=5`

Comment: With `month=MM/day=DD` given I assumed it would be `year=2019/month=09/day=05`, which would sort properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the result of `show partitions` as it would be more efficient as it will hit the metastore only. However, you can't just apply a max to the value there, we will need to construct the date first and then do the max.

Here's a sample:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = sqlContext.sql("show partitions")
df.show(10, False)
date = F.to_date(F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("partition", "[a-z=]", ""), "/", "-"))
df.select(F.max(date).alias("max_date")).show()
```

Input Values:

```py
+------------------------+
|partition               |
+------------------------+
|year=2019/month=11/day=5|
|year=2019/month=9/day=5 |
+------------------------+
```

Result:

```
+----------+
|  max_date|
+----------+
|2019-11-05|
+----------+
```